# Null check for multipart file

Tags: java

I'm processing two different multipart files in my Spring controller.

Both files are then sent on to a service to set the entities. But a `NullPointerException` is being thrown if both or one is null. How do check if either of the two files (`projectImg`/`chartImg`) is null?

Here's my code so far:

```
public void uploadImages(MultipartFile projectImg, MultipartFile chartImg,  Long projectId) throws ValidationException, IOException {
    Project project = projectRepository.findOne(projectId);
    Project save = projectRepository.save(project);

    int maximumSizeMB = 15000000;

    if (!projectImg.isEmpty()) {
        if (projectImg.getSize() > maximumSizeMB) {
            throw new ValidationException("Image size is too big. Maximum size is 15 MB");
        }

        byte[] projectFile = ImageCompression.compressImage(projectImg);
        project.setProjectImg(projectFile);
        save.getProjectImg();
    }
    if (!chartImg.isEmpty()) {
        if (chartImg.getSize() > maximumSizeMB) {
            throw new ValidationException("Image size is too big. Maximum size is 15 MB");
        }

        byte[] chartFile = ImageCompression.compressImage(chartImg);
        project.setChartImg(chartFile);
        save.getChartImg();
    }
    projectRepository.save(project);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `if (projectImg != null)` instead of `.isEmpty()` or before it, maybe?

Comment: btw. `maximumSizeMB` sounds like its unit was megabytes. In that case though, the maximum size would be 15 TB which is quite a lot.

Comment: `if(null != projectImg)` should do the null check without throwing a `NullPointerException`

Comment: @FrakCool That actually worked. Don't know how I could miss that. Thanks!

Comment: @Vlasec Good point, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just for the sake of you to accept an answer and this question doesn't stay as "unanswered", I'll post my comment as an answer:

You can call

```
if (projectImg != null) { ... }
```

before or instead

```
if (projectImg.isEmpty()) { ... }
```

Comment: this doesnt work, some bytes got filed for me even if the file was empty... perhaps the header info. accepted answer needs to be updated

Answer (score 7):

The best way to check if the file is null or not is using the MultipartFile `isEmpty()` method in the following way.

```
if(!chartImg.isEmpty()){
 // your logic here 
}else{
 // your logic here 
}


if(!projectImg.isEmpty()){
// your logic here 
}else{
 // your logic here 
}
```

`if(projectImg != null){ }` does not always work

Answer (score 3):

In Spring Boot 2.1.* `MultipartFile` always gets filled even if it isn't required so the most reliable way to check whether an optional file was sent I've found is

```
if(file.getSize() > 0)
    //file has data
```

for a requestparameter defined as

```
@RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file
```